# PerlLoadModule can't find module

Tags: apache, perl

My workplace has a shared development environment, and I am localing a copy of it.

In the Apache configuration is the following directive:

```
PerlLoadModule MSC::Framework::R0028::Handler::Init::Database
```

When I start Apache, it gives me this error:

```
Can't locate MSC/Framework/R0028/Handler/Init/Database.pm in @INC (@INC contains ... )
```

I have numerous copies of Database.pm, but I'm not sure how in the Apache config the path to this file is specified.

How can I hook this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has nothing to do with Apache. Perl can't find the specified module. Perl looks at the `@INC` variable for a search path. It's built from hardcoded paths, from command-line option `-I` (not applicable here) and from env var `PERL5LIB`, though it can be modified by code too.

[`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC), [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

[Tips from the mod_perl docs](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#Adjusting_C__INC_)